# ruby and sed -n matched group

Tags: ruby, sed

Doing `git config -l | sed -n 's/^user.name=\(.*\)$/{\1}/p'` in the shell will yield the current "user.name" set in the git config. But if I do this same command in backticks `` or with `%x(<shel code>)` in ruby, I get nothing returned.

I've found another way around without using `sed` in this case, but I'm wondering why I can get the output of `sed` without the `-n` flag, which would be whatever is piped to it, but I can never get the matched group (whether it be by itself or part of the stream that `sed` without the `-n` outputs).

Comment: Why don't you just do `git config --get user.name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do most of that in ruby:

```
conf = %x{git config -l}
if m = conf.match(/^user.name=(.*)/) 
  username = m[1]
end
```

To directly answer your question, the text in `%x{}` is subject to the same substitutions as double quoted strings, so you need to escape the backslashes:

```
irb(main):023:0> u = %x{git config -l | sed -n 's/^user.name=\(.*\)$/{\1}/p'}
=> ""
irb(main):024:0> u = %x{git config -l | sed -n 's/^user.name=\\(.*\\)$/{\\1}/p'}
=> "{Glenn Jackman}\n"
```

Or you could store the command in a single quoted string:

```
irb(main):020:0> cmd = %q{git config -l | sed -n 's/^user.name=\(.*\)$/{\1}/p'}
=> "git config -l | sed -n 's/^user.name=\\(.*\\)$/{\\1}/p'"
irb(main):022:0> u = %x{#{cmd}}
=> "{Glenn Jackman}\n"
```

Comment: very nice explanation, this will come in handy in more complex cases for me no doubt